# How to change HEX to ASCII? and error with UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 246: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, hex, ascii

```
d = open("test2.txt",'w')
e = open("test3.pcm",'w')

for line in lines:
    s = pStart.search(line)
    if s != None:
        start = s.end()
        e = pEnd.search(line)
        end = e.start()
        #print(line[start:end])
        d.write(line[start:end])
        d.write('\n')
        d.write(bytes.fromhex(line[start:end]).decode("ASCII"))
```

i want to change HEX txt to ASCII. because i want to transform data to pcm and wav file

and test2.txt file have these txt...

"
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FE FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 FF FF 00 00 FF FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FE FF FE FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
"

but i have this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/soundApp_Ver_1.0.0/test.py", line 88, in 
d.write(bytes.fromhex(line[start:end]).decode("ASCII"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 246: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do add what you tried?Where you got struck?What is your expected output by providing at least 3 to 4 test cases.Please read [Creating-minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Don't%20sacrifice%20clarity%20for,correctly%20formatted%20on%20Stack%20Overflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your described input and output:

```
import re

in_str = "[ABC TEST] CNT(1) S(0) 00 00 12 34 12 34 12 34"
pattern = re.compile('\s([0-9]+)')
s = ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, in_str))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
00 00 12 34 12 34 12 34
```

Which is what you've specified. Repeat the procedure for other string.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove every that is before series of 2 digits by replacing `^.+?(?=(?:\d\d )+)` with nothing.

```py
import re
strings = [
    '[ABC TEST] CNT(1) S(0) 00 00 12 34 12 34 12 34 .....',
    '[ABC TEST] CNT(2) S(0) 00 12 34 56 78 88 12 12 .....',
]
for str in strings:
    res = re.sub(r'^.+?(?=(?:\d\d )+)', '', str)
    print(res)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/92HKsk/1/)